# New Lister app error "The shared application group container is unavailable. Check your entitlements and provisioning profiles for this target..."

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch

I've done everything in the Read Me.

Still after I press play, Simulator runs then crashes with this message:

Failing at **line 175**:

```
let toURL = ListUtilities.localDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
```

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: What is your crash message?

Comment: Here's the error: http://imgur.com/B3kEwHU

Comment: what happend when you add !

Comment: It pulls up another error in the code. This came directly from Apple. The add a ! seems to be a standard Xcode bad suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

You have to change the LISTER_BUNDLE_PREFIX to your company bundle ID, like "com.yourcompany.com", and eventually fix the error in App Group option and iCloud option. The first step must be done before step 2 & 3.

1. First, change the LIST_BUNDLE_PREFIX in project Setting. You find this setting in the "Build Setting" tab of your project (not a target) !!! 
   [image]
2. Fix App Groupe
   [image]
3. Fix iCloud option
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. I also did a search and replace of "com.example.apple-samplecode" with ${LISTER_BUNDLE_PREFIX} throughout my entire project, mainly the various Info.plist files. Finally, I did Product -> Clean before rebuilding to make sure Xcode was not latching onto old data.

Comment: Helped me out a lot. Thanks. I did one more think not mentioned in any of the comments. I changed General-->Identity-->Signing for the OS/X targets to "Developer ID" from "Mac App Store."

It's the usual story, though. Apple's incomplete documentation in their sample code. These were all major items, and not a mention of them.

Comment: same is the case with Xcode 7 and 10.11. Thank you for the helpful steps!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have changed all instances of `com.example.apple-samplecode` in the sample code to be appropriate for your application.  Not doing so will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

If the above doesn't work for you, you may have to refresh Xcode's knowledge of your entitlements by pressing the little circle with an arrow button. And one more thing... Make sure you have the CloudKit framework installed and the CloudKit button checked in your iCloud Capabilities panel.